# Issue about connecting with wifidirect?

Tags: android

I wanna create an application using wifi direct.

In connecting step between 2 devices. I wanna set wifi direct on if wifi direct state of the device use my application is off. Can I change wifi direct state of the device(mobile)? How?

When i send request to connect to another devices Can my application auto accept the request without asking the device received request?

Please support me. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, you can turn on/off the WIFI connection of the handset using the WifiManager:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

WIFI and wifidirect are enabled at the same time. You will need to add the needed permissions to the Android manifest.

Check Android Developers for more information on "http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled(boolean)".

About accepting the connection without human interaction... It should be possible, but only if your app is the one handling the connection at the end-side and you have developed it in a way that will take care of all the steps. However this is not good from an end-user perspective since you are not giving him the power of decision. A nice solution would be doing it manually and allowing the user to decide if allow it automatically for the next time for that specific device.

Please, provide feedback if anything is not clear or does not really answers your questions.